# Limit of continuous sequence of function which is infinite in a dense set, but integrable

Tags: functions

I have to find an increasing sequence of continuous function $f_n(x):[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_n(x)dx<\infty$$
and in the same time $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=\infty$ in a dense set $A$ in $[0,1]$.

I tried to calculate the limit function $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)$. So $f(x)=\infty$ for $x\in A$ and $f(x)$  is finite for $x\notin A$. Furthermore the measure $\mu(A)=0$.

To simplify I set $f(x)=1$ for $x\notin A$ and $f(x)=\infty$ otherwise. Then I have to first choose $A$ and then try to approximate $f$ by a sequence of continuous functions, which poses restraint on $A$. I have no idea how to proceed further.

---

$f$ is a function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ so I'm not sure if it is a Baire function or not. If yes it seems that because $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, it doesn't exist. (due to the criteria of a baire-class 1 function). But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write ${\mathbb Q} \cap [0,1] = \{r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots\},$ let $E_n = \{r_1,r_2, \ldots, r_n\},$ and define $f_n$ by $f_n(x) = n$ if $x \in E_n$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. Note that the integral of each $f_n$ is $0$ (more than you asked for) and we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = \infty$ for each $x \in {\mathbb Q}.$

You can get a sequence of continuous functions (but the integrals will no longer be $0)$ by using, for $f_n,$ appropriately tall and thin triangles placed over $r_1,$ $r_2,$ $\ldots,$ $r_n.$

**CORRECTION**

The construction with triangles isn't going to get an increasing sequence, at least not unless you stack them very carefully. Instead, maybe try the following. Letting ${\chi}_E$ the the characteristic function of $E$ (the function that equals $1$ at each point in $E$ and equals $0$ at each point not in $E),$ define $f_{k,m} = k \cdot {\chi}_{[r_m - 2^{-km}, \; r_m + 2^{-km}]}$ (include an intersection with $[0,1],$ of course, to get the domain to be $[0,1])$ and let $f_n$ be the sum from $k=1$ to $k=n$ and $m=1$ to $m=n$ (a sum with $n^2$ many terms) of $f_{k,m}.$ What you're getting will look like stacked building blocks that get more and more densely distributed in $[0,1]$ and get stacked higher and higher (but narrower as you get higher). The functions $f_{k,m}$ are not continuous, but I think you can very slightly round the corners to get continuity (i.e. no vertical building sides) while maintaining the features you want. Surely there's a more elegant way than this, but I can't think of anything better and I have to go to a meeting now.

Comment: Since he wants the $f_n$ to be increasing, I think this won't work or how exactly do you want to do it with the triangles?

Comment: Increasing sequence means $\forall x: f_{n+1}(x)\ge f_n(x)$.

Comment: @menag: Yeah, there might be a problem here. I added the continuous part before he even included this in the main body of the question (I didn't notice "continuous" in the title), as an afterthought that apparently wasn't thought over enough!

Comment: Thanks I've constructed the needed sequence. Hope I didn't make any mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

Take $f_n = -{1 \over n} 1_{\mathbb{Q}^c} + n \cdot 1_\mathbb{Q}$.

Then $\int f_n = -{1 \over n}$, but
$\lim_n f_n(q) = \infty$ for $q \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

**Continuous function**:

If you want continuous, let $q_n$ be an enumeration of the
rationals in $[0,1]$.

Let $\phi_{m,n}(x) = \max(0,1-e^{n+m} |x-q_n|)$ and note that $\phi_{m,n} \ge 0$ and
$\int \phi_{m,n} \le e^{-(m+n)} $.

Now let $f_N = \sum_{m=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{m,n}$, note that $f_N(x)$ is
increasing as a function of $N$ and $\int f_N \le {1 \over (1-e)^2}$.

Since $\phi_{m,n}(q_n) = 1$ for all $m$, we see that $f_N(q_n) \to \infty$.

Comment: It's not continuous...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that $f_n$ has to be continuous.

Comment: Anything else? :-)

Comment: Really sorry. I think that's all....

Comment: @Mr.T: I added a continuous version...

Comment: Yes it's in the same idea as Dave. Thanks very much.

Comment: Well, not exactly the same idea, if you add a triangle to each rational of the height given, and the $f_n$ are increasing, the  integral will be unbounded. The general idea is right, but the construction is a little more delicate than adding a single triangle to each rational.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]=\{r_1,r_2,r_3,\cdots\}$, and set
$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} (|x-r_k|+1/n)^{-1/2}$.